# Visual Studio keeps asking to install SQL Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-express

I am using Visual Studio 2012 working on a web application, a registration page. I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express and done the configuration but still when when I try to add a SQL Server database file in the project, I get an error

> Connection to SQL Server Database file (.mdf) requires SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 Express to be installed and running on you local computer

Please help I am stuck here.

Comment: What version of SQL server you instadded?? Did you install Local DB? or just management studio?

Comment: Show us your connectionstring in the web config

Comment: I downloaded it from here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=1695

Comment: it gives error when I click add new in the project in visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the LocalDB or to change your connection string to use the SQL server you have installed, it seems like you are trying to use a MDF file.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 doesn't have a "LocalDB" version (that was introduced in SQL Server **2012** ....)

Comment: Yes but visual studio 2012 does have it.

Comment: Only if you install the included SQL Server **2012** Express LocalDB .... if you've installed SQL Server **2008** Express before, then you **don't have** LocalDB :...